# Make a one sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algorithms

A sequence of integers is a one- sequence if the difference between any two consecutive numbers in this sequence is -1 or 1 and its first element is 0.

More precisely: a1, a2, ..., an is a one-sequence if:

```
For any k (1 ≤  k < n): |a[k] - a[k+1]|=1, 
a[1]=0.
```

Given n and s ─ sum of all elements in a. W need to construct a one-sequence with the given parameters.

Like If n=8 and s=4 then one of such sequence is [0 1 2 1 0 -1 0 1].

Note if for given n and s we cant form such sequence than also we need to tell that its not possible.Otherwise we need to tell any of such one sequence.How to do this problem Please help.

Comment: Try some special cases. Fix $n=2$ and see which values of $s$ you can get. Then try $n=3$, then $n=4$, keep going until you see a pattern. Worth a try, I think.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I tried.But cant come up with a general sequence.Always got a catch for whatever i think off..:(

Comment: Come on. $n=2$. There are only 2 sequences possible; $0,1$ and $0,-1$, so the only values of $s$ are $1$ and $-1$. Now, you do $n=3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson For small n its a cakewalk.But as n grew it becomes difficult to maintain the sum required

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "maintain the sum required". I don't require any sum. I suggest writing down all the sequences, and seeing which sums arise. Alternatively, pick a sum, say, $s=0$, and see whether you can get it with $n=1$, then with $n=2$, $n=3$, and so on, until you see a pattern in which values of $n$ work for that value of $s$. Then try the same with $s=1$, and so on. Show us your work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Given a sequence of length $n$ summing to $s$, we can create two sequences of length $n+1$ summing to $s-n$ and to $s+n$, and this process is reversible. By induction, the possible sums for sequences of length $n+1$ are $\pm n \pm (n-1) \pm (n-2) \cdots \pm (1)$, where we can choose the signs independently. By considering this expression modulo $2$, we see that $s \equiv n(n+1)/2 \pmod{2}$, and also trivially $-n(n+1)/2 \leq s \leq n(n+1)/2$.

Given a number $s$ satisfying these two constraints, define $s' = s \pm n$, choosing the sign so that $-n(n-1)/2 \leq s' \leq n(n-1)/2$. Also, $s' \equiv n(n+1)/2-n \equiv n(n-1)/2 \pmod{2}$. Induction therefore shows that any sum satisfying the constraints is achievable, and the proof can be turned into an algorithm.

Note that this is only a hint so I only sketch the argument. You'll have to fill in the details on your own.